# What should be under <system.runtime.remoting> </system.runtime.remoting> in BTSNTSvc64.exe.config file?

Tags: c#, .net, biztalk

Can anybody tell me that what should be under

`<system.runtime.remoting>`  in BTSNTSvc64.exe.config file

Answer (score 1, accepted):

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa560795.aspx

```
<system.runtime.remoting>

    <channelSinkProviders>
        <serverProviders>
            <provider id="sspi" type="Microsoft.BizTalk.XLANGs.BTXEngine.SecurityServerChannelSinkProvider,Microsoft.XLANGs.BizTalk.Engine" securityPackage="ntlm" authenticationLevel="packetPrivacy" />
        </serverProviders>
    </channelSinkProviders>

    <application>
        <channels>
            <channel ref="tcp" port="0" name="">
            <serverProviders>
                <provider ref="sspi" />
                    <formatter ref="binary" typeFilterLevel="Full"/>
                </serverProviders>
            </channel>
        </channels>
    </application>
</system.runtime.remoting>
```